# Azure DevOps pipeline trigger variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, continuous-integration, yaml

We have this below scenario -

Pipeline 1 triggers pipeline 2 and also send variables **$(path1), $(path2), $(path3)**... to pipeline 2.

I'm trying to find a way to do a `for-each` loop for the variables which are being sent from pipeline1.

We are using YAML for the setup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @AnuraagVodnala, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please have a try with it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Hi @Bright Ran-MSFT - Things are going good. I'm able to make this work. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use each function

```
parameters:
steps:
- ${{ each p in parameters.pipeline1vars }}:
  - script: echo ${{ p }}
```

Comment: How can we do a loop with parameter and retrieve a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we can use the expression "**`resources.pipeline.<Alias>.<var_name>`**" to only pass some **predefined variables** of the resource pipeline to the triggered pipeline (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pipeline-resource-variables)).

We have no way to directly pass the custom variables from the resource pipeline to the triggered pipeline.

However, you can reference to the article below to try passing the variables through pipeline artifact.

- [**How to pass variables with pipeline trigger in Azure Pipeline**](https://tsuyoshiushio.medium.com/how-to-pass-variables-with-pipeline-trigger-in-azure-pipeline-5771c5f18f91)

You can save all the variables you want to pass into the artifact file. And in the triggered pipeline, you can try to use a loop to read each variable saved in the file.